# Extract json array element based on a subelement value

Tags: text-processing, json, jq

We have the following example file ( very long file , this is short example )

```
"request_status" : "FAILED"
{
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/sys41/requests/333",
    "Requests" : {
        "cluster_name" : "sys41",
        "id" : 333,
        "request_status" : "COMPLETED"
    }
},
{
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/sys41/requests/334",
    "Requests" : {
        "cluster_name" : "sys41",
        "id" : 334,
        "request_status" : "FAILED"
    }
},
{
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/sys41/requests/335",
    "Requests" : {
        "cluster_name" : "sys41",
        "id" : 335,
        "request_status" : "FAILED"
    }
},
{
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/sys41/requests/336",
    "Requests" : {
        "cluster_name" : "sys41",
        "id" : 336,
        "request_status" : "COMPLETED"
    }
}
```

how to print the line after the line that matches `"id" : $num`
e.g. for

```
num=335
```

how to get the line after

```
"id" : $num
```

Expected output

```
"request_status" : "FAILED"
```

Comment: This looks like a job for `jq` which is the tool specifically built for querying JSON objects, but I am not fluent enough to impart unto you the correct incantation.

Comment: Could you please post a less broken JSON file?  It's difficult to come up with a proper `jq` solution when the JSON is so severely mangled at the top.

Comment: If it's really json you're dealing with, then be careful using solutions that assume a fixed number of spaces around the colons (and all the other flexible parts of the json spec!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the shell variable `num` set equal to `335`:

```
grep -A1 "\"id\" : $num," /path/to/file
```

I get a lot of mileage out of `grep`'s handy `-A`, `-B`, and `-C` options, the mnemonics for which I use are "After", "Before", and "Context".

- `grep -A n 'pattern' file` will show the *n* lines **A**fter a pattern match, in addition to the matching line itself.
- `grep -C n 'pattern' file` will show the *n* lines **B**efore a pattern match, in addition to the matching line itself.
- `grep -C n 'pattern' file` will show the *n* lines both before *and* after (i. e. the **C**ontext of) a pattern match, in addition to the matching line itself.

Comment: For less toothpicks: `grep -A1 '"id" : '"$num," ...`

Comment: Just as many toothpicks; they're just shorter (:

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the JSON file is one big array of objects such as

```
  {
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/sys41/requests/333",
    "Requests": { "id": 333, "cluster_name": "sys41", "request_status": "COMPLETED" }
  },
```

(noting that newlines are not significant, and neither is the ordering of the keys in an object) then, the following `jq` command would get the `request_status` entry for the `id` corresponding to `$num`:

```
$ num=355
$ jq -r ".[].Requests | select(.id == $num).request_status" file.json
FAILED
```

It does this by picking out all the `Requests` entries from each object and filtering them on the `id`.  For the ones that pass the filter, it extracts `request_status`.

The `-r` option to `jq` makes it output raw data instead of JSON (`FAILED` would have been double quoted without it).

---

Bonus material:

```
$ jq -r '.[].Requests | "\(.id): \(.request_status)"' file.json
333: COMPLETED
334: FAILED
335: FAILED
336: COMPLETED
```

Comment: jq is the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/"id" : 335/{getline;print}'
```

or

```
var="\"id\" : 335"
awk "/$var/{getline;print}"
```

or

```
awk -v var="\"id\" : 335" '$0~var{getline;print}'
```

or

```
var="\"id\" : 335"
awk -v var="$var" '$0~var{getline;print}'
```

or any of the above, but without needing the `"id" : "` part of the string, in the form:

```
awk -v var="335" '$0~"id" : var{getline;print}'
```

Comment: May not work as intended.  For example, will show a false match for `"id" : 1355`.

Comment: Did you try that and have it fail?

Comment: Oh, I see - you mean that I just pulled the rong text for the search. That's easy to replace.